# Creating a CloudFormation Stack from a Existing AMI Snapshot

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I am very new to cloudformation, so excuse my ignorance. I have been trying to create a cloudformation template form a existing linux AMI snapshot as a basis for automating my current resources and eventually have my entire infrastructure running on a cloudformation template. is there a way i can use the AMI snapshot as a basis for the stack or do I have to create everything from scratch and then update it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated for this noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a LaunchConfiguration and one of the properties for the launch config is the ImageID for the AMI snapshot. Note that you will need an AMI snapshot for each region you want to support based on my past experience. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html